# Is there a predefined macro for Configuration type in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, predefined-macro

I am using CDT for building a system comprised of many projects. Some of the system elements are dependent on the Configuration type - Debug or Release.

I am aware that there is nothing utterly special in these names, and that I can define my own configurations. However, since these two are built-in, is there a predefined macro to tell if the active configuration is one or the other?

Because there are many projects in the system, adding a `_DEBUG_`, `_RELEASE_` symbols to each is somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such macro would have to be passed to the compiler. There is no such macro in the generated makefiles.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, you seem to be right - the config name is hardcoded in the auto generated makefiles.